# sending two different messages on click off Togglebutton

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a **ToggleButton**. When that button is clicked once, the Byte[] containing the message {(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02} has to be sent to server and when the same button is clicked again the Byte[] containing the msg {(byte)0xFE,(byte)0x01} has to be sent to the server.
My **client code** is like this.

```
Public void onClick(View v)
 {
  if(v.getId()==R.id.btncon)
   {
    if(con.isChecked())
     {
      new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run()
        {
         try{
          InetAddress in=InetAddress.getByName(host);
          s=new Socket(in,port);
          PrintStream pw=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
          pw.println(message);

          InputStream inp=new InputStream(s.getInputStream());
          BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(inp);
          String user=br.readline();
          Log.d("home",user);
            }
         catch(IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }).start();
   }
 else
  { 
   try{
    PrintStream pw1=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.Println(message1);
    s.close();
      }
  catch(IOException e1)
      {
       e1.printStackTrace();
      }}}}
```

my **server code** is

```
public void run() throws Exception
 {
   String MESSAGE;    
   ServerSocket ss=null;
   PrintStream pw=null;
    try 
     {
      ss=new ServerSocket(8002);
     }
   catch(IOException e1)
     {
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }

   while(true)
    {
     try
      {               

       sock=ss.accept();
       in=new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());     
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);

       MESSAGE=br.readLine();          
       System.out.println("client sent:"+MESSAGE);

    if(MESSAGE!=null)
     {
      pw=new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
      pw.println("server received the message"+":"+ MESSAGE);
      pw.flush();
     }}                  
  catch(IOException e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 finally{
   in.close();
   pw.close();
   sock.close();
        }}}
```

When message is send from the client, when server recieves and prints the value i am getting a different value.I want the output to be displayed as it is sent.
please help.Thanks in advance.

A code for both server and client would be helpful

Comment: Please format your code properly it will be easy to read.

Comment: I posted two questions but i am not getting any responses for my question....help would be useful..please

Comment: Are you sending and receiving with the same encoding?

Comment: ya.A code for this would be helpful